# How to add DisplayName with email + password authentication in Firebase? Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
private void registerUser(){
String emailId = email.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
String password = pass.getText().toString().trim();

firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailId,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //show chatroom
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Failed. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I wish to add a username or display name to it but am unable to do so. I tried a few things but still no result. Kindly help me. I need this functionality for a project submission this week.

Comment: your can't do that using FirebaseAuth, if you have to store user details you  will need to manually do that using RealtimeDatabase

Comment: @SakchhamSharma There is a way to do it, just not directly when creating a new user. See my answer below :)

Comment: @edant92 I ment at the time of creation

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely possibly but just not in the user creation method.

Once you've created your user (possibly in the `addOnSuccessListener`) you can use something similar to the following code to update the Users DisplayName:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName("John Smith").build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: I previously said to add the code to the AuthStateListener, however, Frank's suggestion below to put it in the addOnSuccessListener is better/makes more sense so I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Good answer! I would probably do this in the `addOnSuccessListener`, since you'd usually only want to set the name when you create the account.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently investigated this issue for my own implementation (SDK version 4.4.1). What I've found is that it works perfectly if you are sure to utilize the exact same task.result object from registration/login and not the object from the default instance.

Another work around that helped me is to have an email reference table in your FB DB like this:

```
{ "EmailRef": { "username1" : "email@ domain .com"}, {"username2" : "email2@domain.com"} }
```

And then to query for the username by the user's email (from auth.CurrentUser.Email) using a method like this:

```
public static void GetCurrentUserName(Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user)
{
    string message = "";
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FbDbConnection();
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("EmailRef").OrderByValue().EqualTo(user.Email).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            message = "GetCurrentUserName encountered an error: " + task.Exception;
            ModalManager.BuildFireBaseDebugModal(message);
            Debug.LogError(message);
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            message = "GetCurrentUserName was canceled.";
            Debug.LogError(message);
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            foreach (DataSnapshot ss in task.Result.Children.AsEnumerable())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ss.Value != null)
                    {
                        if (ss.Value.ToString() == user.Email)
                        {
                            message = "GetCurrentUserName was successful -- Email: " + user.Email + " Username: " + user.DisplayName;
                            Debug.LogError(message);
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    message = "GetCurrentUserName Exception: " + ex;
                    Debug.LogError(message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```