# how to use cloud functions to save user's displayName when creating account in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Question: When a user account is created, how to use cloud functions to save his displayName to realtime DB in firebase

The scenario steps:

1. I have a signup page containing `email, password, displayName` fields,
   to allow users to create new account in firebase
2. Above page will 1) trigger `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create
   the user account, 2) save `displayName` value to userProfile in Auth DB.
3. In Cloud function,  the code below is used so new user's email can
   be saved to DB `users` node.

`` exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => 
    return admin.database().ref(`/users/${event.data.uid}`).update
    ({email: event.data.email}) ``

4. I wish to save `displayName` to `users` node with above code, but it seems not possible because it is not in the context of `event` in `onCreate`.

What shall I do? It becomes nasty if I need to use both client and cloud function to update `users` node.

Best regards,
D

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `firebase.User.updateProfile()` method to update the `displayName` once the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` method completes. Like this -

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {

}).then(function (user) {
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: "Jane Q. User",//pass displayName from your signup form here
            photoURL: "<image-url>"//you can pass this empty
        }).then(function () {
            //redirect to your post-registration page
        });
})
```

Comment: I did try this and thought it was the solution. However, a race condition is introduced. Both `functions.auth.user().onCreate` and `updateProfile` asynchronically attempt to update `displayName`. Why does cloud functions update displayName? Because if the user is created from 3rd party provider (google, facebook etc.), `event.data.displayName` is given.

Comment: It seems to me that use client code to update all information for `users` node is more elegent than splitting between cloud functions and client code.

Comment: Yes. In your use-case cloud functions will try to execute in parallel. I would also suggest to go with pure client-side logic. Firebase client-side APIs have been designed well and can handle Promise-based multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) for auth events suggests the displayName is accessible via `event.data.displayName`.  If you are seeing any other behavior, it's a bug or you might be doing something wrong that you're not mentioning here.

Comment: My problem is that when use email&password to create account, there seems no way to pass a 'display' in. If  user uses Oauth with Facebook or google, the 'displayName' is retrieved from providers and accessible.

Comment: Maybe you could try setting it immediately after creation on the client to see if it commits before the function triggers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804867/how-to-add-displayname-with-email-password-authentication-in-firebase-android

Comment: Thanks! your comment is similar to Dhruv proposed below. I think I should drop cloud functions for on-user-creating event and do everything from client side. The original reason to use cloud function is, it is 100% guaranteed to run comparing to client code.